# SQL Server : increase the value by one in a field where matching foreign key id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is probably really easy for someone good at SQL, at that someone isn't me!

I have a database table with two fields in it.  the id field is a fk id to another table, and the other field displayorder currently contains all 1's.

I want to, as below, update display order by one, starting at 1 each time the fk id changes.  I am using SQL Server.  This is what is should look like in the end:-

```
FKID     displayorder
---------------------
1          1
2          1
2          2
3          1
3          2
3          3
4          1
4          2
5          1
5          2
5          3
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT FKID,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS displayorder
FROM table
ORDER BY FKID;
```

Update:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FKID, displayorder,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS do
    FROM table
)
UPDATE cte
SET displayorder = do;
```

Please keep in mind that to get stable sort you should `ORDER BY` some column like PK/timestamp.

Comment: Thanks.  How is that implemented so that I can perform an Update as currently all entries in displayorder are 1 and I want to update them to be incremental as above please?